# How to write an inline block to contain local variable scope in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In JavaScript the following idiom is sometimes used to contain scope

```
// JavaScript
(function() {
    var x = 0;
    // do stuff
})(); // execute anonymous function in-place

// x is undefined (or its previous value)
```

And you see this in Perl:

```
{
    local $/ = undef;
    $file_contents = <FILE>;
}
# $/ == "\n"
```

Is there something similar in Ruby?  The closest I could come up with was:

```
Proc.new
    x = 123
    puts x
end.call
# x is undefined
```

Is there another, more common way to do this in Ruby or is this how it's best done?

Comment: Your proposed way seems like the easiest solution. What is your use-case for it, out of curiosity? In JavaScript I can see it being useful to prevent clients from manipulating global variables, or to prevent collisions with other global variables when including various script files, but those are no issues in Ruby.

Comment: Use case is nothing important or permanent.  I'm relatively new to Ruby and find myself writing temporary scripts to try out several approaches to a problem.  Within the script, I wanted to keep each "trial block" scope isolated when I'm trying a few things at once.  I originally tried a bare "do...end" block, which doesn't work, somewhat to my surprise.

Comment: I would just create several methods, where each method would keep its local variables to itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example won’t work if `x` is already defined before the block:

```
x = 7
Proc.new do
    x = 123
    puts x
end.call
# x is now 123
```

Ruby does allow you to specify block local variables in the block argument list with this rather obscure syntax:

```
x = 7
Proc.new do |;x| # declare x as block local
    x = 123
    puts x
end.call
# x is still 7
```

Any variables after the `;` are treated as local to that block and don’t effect similarly named variables in the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

Closest solution would be to use stabby lambda notation:

```
-> {
  x = 123
  puts x
}.call
```

It is not very common in Ruby to use anonymous procs in such context. The most ruby-way of which I can think of is enclosing each trial in small, lightweight class.

Answer (score 0):

Using a proc

```
proc {
  ...
}[]
```

is already pretty minimal, though not very idiomatic. You can write your own wrapper, which you might find more elegant as it avoids the creation of an anonymous function

```
def wrap
  yield
end

wrap do
  ...
end
```

However, as @matt pointed out, this doesn't prevent you from accessing variables defined outside the block.