# Syntax for Block Local Variables

Tags: ruby, syntax, convention

I am confused about a good style to adopt to define block local variables. The choices are:

Choice A:

```
method_that_calls_block { |v, w| puts v, w }
```

Choice B:

```
method_that_calls_block { |v; w| puts v, w }
```

The confusion is compunded when I want the block local to have a default value. The choices I am confused about are:

Choice C:

```
method_that_calls_block { |v, w = 1| puts v, w }
```

Choice D:

```
method_that_calls_block { |v, w: 1| puts v, w }
```

Is there a convention about how block local variables must be defined?

P.S. Also it seems the `;` syntax does not work when I need to assign default value to a block local variable! Strange.

Comment: It doesn’t make any sense to use the `;` syntax for assigning default values, the variables after the `;` are not parameters to the block, you are just declaring that the block will use them and Ruby shouldn’t overwrite any existing local variables with the same name when you do.

Comment: @matt I was wondering if block-local variables could be initialized also. As it turns out, it is forbidden. You're also right about using the `;` block-local syntax only if I wan to shadow a variable with the same name in the outer scope.

Comment: A default value is there so that if the block is called without a value for that parameter it will use the default. Since you _never_ provide a value for the block local vars having a default makes no sense. You can just initialise them to whatever you want in the block itself, safe in the knowledge that you won’t clobber any existing vars.

Comment: @matt, I also assumed that was the case, but then ran (v.2.1) this, which I thought could be potentially useful: `[[1,2], [3]].map { |f,s=4| [f,s] } => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`. Did I misunderstand what you are saying?

Comment: Note also that *disambiguation* of, and the use of *placeholders* for, block variables are techniques that often can be employed to improve readability. Suppose, for example, that you are passing a an array `a = [a0, [a1, a2], a3]` into a block, but you will only use the element `a2`. Disambiguation allows you to write this as `|a0,(a1,a2),a3|` and the use of placeholders allows further simplification to `|_,(_,a2,_)|`, which can be shortened to `|_,(_,a2)|`. Similarly, disambiguation allows you to write `hash.each_with_object([]) { |(k,v),arr|...}`. –  Cary Swoveland 41 mins ago

Comment: Providing a default value to a block _parameter_ (as in `|f,s=4| [f,s]`) is okay (and useful). Providing a default value to a _block local_ isn’t much use (i.e. `|f;s=4| ...`) and will give an error. Using `;` isn’t just an alternative to using `,` – anything before the semicolon is a parameter, anything after is a block local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Choice B is not valid.</strike> As @matt indicated - it is a valid (though obscure) syntax (see here: [How to write an inline block to contain local variable scope in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22789497/214790))

Choice C gives a default value to `w`, which is a regular value, while Choice D is a syntax for default [keyword argument](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/).

Comment: So do you recommend choices C & D over others?

Comment: A, C & D are for different use cases - A when you pass two values, C when you pass one _or_ two values, and D when you pass a value and a hash...

Comment: “Choice B is not valid.” – that is the syntax used to declare varaible local to the block so that you don’t overwrite existing local variable: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22789497/214790. It is a bit obscure though.

Answer (score 1):

All four of these are valid, but they all have different semantics -- which is correct depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

#### Examples

Consider the following method, which yields multiple values.

```rb
def frob
  yield 1, 2, 3
end
```

#### Choice A: block parameters

"Get me the first two yielded values, if any, I don't care about the others."

```rb
frob { |v, w| [v, w].inspect}
# => "[1, 2]"
```

#### Choice B: block parameter + block-local variable

"Get me the first value, I don't care about the others; and give me an additional, uninitialized variable".

```rb
frob { |v; w| [v, w].inspect}
# => "[1, nil]"
```

#### Choice C: block parameters, some with default values

"Get me the first two values, and if the second value isn't initialized, set that variable to 1":

```rb
frob { |v, w = 1| [v, w].inspect }
# => "[1, 2]" <-- all values are present, default value ignored
```

"Get me the first five values, and if the fifth value isn't initialized, set that variable to 99":

```rb
frob { |v, w, x, y, z = 99| [v, w, x, y, z].inspect }
# => "[1, 2, 3, nil, 99]"
```

#### Choice D: positional and keyword block parameters

"Get me the first value, and if the method yields a keyword parameter `w`, get that, too; if not, set it to 1."

```rb
frob { |v, w: 1| [v, w].inspect }
# => "[1, 1]"
```

This is designed for the case where a method **does** yield block parameters:

```rb
def frobble
  yield 1, 2, 3, w: 4
end
frobble { |v, w: 1| [v, w].inspect }
# => "[1, 4]"
```

In Ruby < 2.7, a block with a keyword parameter will also destructure a hash, although Ruby 2.7 will give you a [deprecation warning](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/), just as if you'd passed a hash to a method that takes keyword arguments:

```rb
def frobnitz
  h = {w: 99}
  yield 1, 2, 3, h
end

# Ruby 2.7
frobnitz { |v, w: 1| [v, w].inspect }
# warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
# => "[1, 99]"
```

Ruby 3.0 doesn't give you a deprecation warning, but it also ignores the hash:

```rb
# Ruby 3.0
frobnitz { |v, w: 1| [v, w].inspect }
# => [1, 1]
```

Yielding an explicit keyword argument still works as expected in 3.0, though:

```rb
# Ruby 3.0
frobble { |v, w: 1| [v, w].inspect }
# => "[1, 4]"
```

Note that the keyword argument form will fail if the method yields unexpected keywords:

```rb
def frobnicate
  yield 1, 2, 3, w: 99, z: -99
end
frobnicate { |v, w: 1| [v, w].inspect }
# => ArgumentError (unknown keyword: :z)
```

### Array destructuring

Another way in which the differences become obvious is when considering a method that returns an array:

```rb
def gork
  yield [1, 2, 3]
end
```

Passing a block with a single argument will get you the whole array:

```rb
gork { |v| v.inspect }
# => "[1, 2, 3]"
```

Passing a block with multiple arguments, though, will get you the elements of the array, even if you pass too few arguments, or too many:

```rb
gork { |v, w| [v, w].inspect }
# "[1, 2]" 
gork { |v, w, x, y| [v, w, x, y].inspect }
# => "[1, 2, 3, nil]"
```

Here again the `;` syntax for block-local variables can come in handy:

```rb
gork { |v; w| [v, w].inspect }
# => "[[1, 2, 3], nil]"
```

Note, though, that even a keyword argument will still cause the array to be destructured:

```rb
gork { |v, w: 99| [v, w].inspect }
# => "[1, 99]"
gork { |v, w: 99; x| [v, w, x].inspect }
# => "[1, 99, nil]"
```

### Outer variable shadowing

Ordinarily, if you use the name of an outer variable inside a block, you're using that variable:

```rb
w = 1; frob { |v| w = 99}; w
# => 99
```

You can avoid this with any of the choices above; any of them will *shadow* the outer variable, hiding the outer variable from the block and ensuring that any effects the block has on it are local.

Choice A: block parameters:

```rb
w = 1; frob { |v, w| puts [v, w].inspect; w = 99}; w
# [1, 2]
# => 1
```

Choice B: block parameter + block-local variable

```rb
w = 1; frob { |v; w| puts [v, w].inspect; w = 99}; w
# [1, nil]
# => 1
```

Choice C: block parameters, some with default values

```rb
w = 1; frob { |v, w = 33| puts [v, w].inspect; w = 99}; w
# [1, 2]
# => 1
```

Choice D: positional and keyword block parameters

```rb
w = 1; frob { |v, w: 33| puts [v, w].inspect; w = 99}; w
# [1, 33]
# => 1
```

The other behavioral differences, though, still hold.

### Default values

You can't set a default value for block-local variables.

```rb
frob { |v; w = 1| [v, w].inspect }
# syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '|'
```

You also can't use a keyword argument as a block parameter.

```
frob { |v; w: 1| [v, w].inspect }
# syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '|'
```

If you **know** the method you're calling doesn't yield a block parameter, though, you can declare a fake block parameter with a default value, and use that to get yourself a pre-initialized block-local variable. Repeated from the first Choice D example, above:

```rb
frob { |v, w: 1| [v, w].inspect }
# => "[1, 1]"
```