# Do block-local variables exist just to enhance readability?

Tags: ruby, scope, block

Block-local variables are to prevent a block from tampering with variables outside of its scope.

*Using a block-local variable*

```
x = 10
3.times do |y; x|
  x = y
end
x # => 10
```

But this is easily done by declaring a regular block parameter. A new local scope is created for that parameter, which takes precedence over previous variables/scopes.

*Without using a block-local variable*

```
x = 10
3.times do |y, x|
  x = y
end
x # => 10
```

The variable `x` outside the block doesn't get changed in either case. Is there any need for block-local variables other than for enhancing readability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block parameter is a real parameter, while a block local variable is not.

If you give `yield` two parameters like this:

```
def foo
  yield("hello", "world")
end
```

Calling

```
x = 10
foo do |y; x|
  puts x
end
```

`x` is `nil` inside the function because only the first argument is assigned to `y`, the second argument is discarded.

Calling

```
x = 10
foo do |y, x|
  puts x
end
#=>world
```

`x` gets the parameter correctly as `"world"`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Yu Hao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26133494/27358), the difference between block parameters and block-local  not obvious when calling a method that only yields one value, but consider a method that yields multiple values:

```rb
def frob
  yield 1, 2, 3
end
```

If you pass this a block with a single argument, you get the first value:

```rb
frob { |a| a.inspect }
# => "1"
```

But if you pass a block with multiple arguments, you get multiple values, even if you pass too few arguments, or too many:

```
frob { |a, b, c| [a, b, c].inspect }
# => "[1, 2, 3]"
frob { |a, b| [a, b].inspect }
# => "[1, 2]" 
frob { |a, b, c, d| [a, b, c, d].inspect }
# => "[1, 2, 3, nil]"
```

If you pass block-scoped variables, however, those are independent of the yielded value(s):

```rb
frob { |a; b, c| [a, b, c].inspect }
# => "[1, nil, nil]"
```

Something similar happens with methods that yield an array, except that when you pass a block with a single argument, it gets the whole array:

```rb
def frobble
  yield [1, 2, 3]
end

frobble {|a| a.inspect }
# => "[1, 2, 3]"
```

Multiple arguments, however, destructure the array --

```rb
frobble {|a, b| [a, b].inspect }
# => "[1, 2]"
```

-- while a block-scoped variable doesn't:

```rb
frobble {|a; b| [a, b].inspect }
# => "[[1, 2, 3], nil]"
```

(Even with a block-scoped variable present, though, multiple values will still destructure the array: `frobble {|a, b; c| [a, b, c].inspect }` will get you `"[1, 2, nil]"`.)

For more discussion and examples, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65929193/27358).